# solution of a Cauchy's problem defined in $(0,+\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis

I have this Cauchy's problem $x^2y'+y^2-1=0$,   $y(2)=a,  a \in R$.
The DE is a Riccati's equation and I found this solution:

constant solution : $y(x)=+1, y(x)=-1$

general integral: $y(x)=\frac{2ce^{-2/x}+1}{2ce^{-2/x}-1}$ with $c \in R$

How can I find for which a the solution is defined on $(0,+\infty)$?

Comment: If you know the general form of the solution, can't you just plug in $x=2$ and solve for $a$?

Comment: $y(2)=\frac{2c+e}{2c-e}=a$

Comment: Have I to found c in function of a?